# Call a Stored procedure in SQL CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

Are you allowed to exec stored procedures within a SQL CTE statement? I'm a bit new to sql cte  queries...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, sorry. SELECTs statments only

If you need to use stored proc output (result set), then it'd be a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar int...)

INSERT #foo (bar, ...)
EXEC myStoredProc @param1...

-- more code using #foo
```

Comment: @Revious: I think yes but it depends on version. Older versions (SQL 2000, maybe SQL Server 2005) don't allow it

Comment: do you know how to write it?

Comment: @Revious I don't know what you mean now. Ask another question if it is more than changing `CREATE TABLE #foo"...`to `DECLARE @foo TABLE...`

Comment: @gbn what if we have dynamic number of columns. Means sometimes sp return 1 column, sometimes 2 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use table variable :

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id int ,name varchar(500) ,...)      
    INSERT INTO @tbl        
    EXEC myprocedure @param ..

with cte as (
    SELECT * FROM @tbl  
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Just don't if you expect more than 1 row.