# Is possible to use the resultset returned from a stored procedure in a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to do something similar to the following code:

```
WITH temp as (EXEC @return_value = [Transactions].[Myproc]
  @Id = 1)
SELECT * from temp
```

Is it possible in T-SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555502/using-temp-table-with-exec-sql-in-stored-procedure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/6332509/call-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-cte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332509/call-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-cte)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure

Comment: The answer in this question is not complete and completely improveable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332509/call-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-cte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
AS
    SELECT employee,first_name,last_name FROM employee_info
GO
```

And here is an example utilizing the resultset returned by the procedure:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeInfo as Table (
employee int,
first_name varchar(40),
last_name varchar(40)
)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeInfo 
EXEC sp_test

SELECT * FROM @EmployeeInfo WHERE employee < 100 ORDER BY last_name
```