# How to use stored procedure inside CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple select query in a stored procedure and I have to get the items from a stored procedure and select in the CTE. What is the syntax for it (if possible without using a temp table)

Comment: Refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332509/call-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-cte

Comment: This again uses the Temp table

Comment: you can't use stored procedure inside a CTE

Comment: It's not possible using a CTE

Comment: OK, can I use the temp table instead of CTE then insert data from sp into temp table ? I have to create around 100 temp table then as per requirement!!

Comment: What's the functional requirement you're trying to meet?

Comment: Can't you use a table valued function instead of a stored procedure? If it is a simple select, you should be able to do so.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got Same Type of Error Yesterday....

My Problem is that with Error...

[image]

I solved my problem using print with SemiColon..

you can check this picture

[image]

So..basically...you have to do ...put this line above CTE function in stored procedure

**PRINT 'This Semicolumn is mandatory here ' ;**

Comment: Why don't you just end all statements with a semicolon. Semicolon is the statement terminator in T-SQL, it is a good practice to use it. Not ending Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017 | On another note, this does not answer the question.